# How to set Session timeout and after timeout or if user close the browser Use Update Query

Tags: php, query-string

```
**How to update table on session timeout**

$_SESSION['start'] = time();
$_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (1 * 60); 
if (isset($_SESSION['Seats']))
{

**if session start then update first query**

    $seatS=$_SESSION['Seats'];
    $Eventid=$_POST["Eventid"];




$stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE fistevent SET `Status`="Hold" where `Event_Id`=? AND `seats`="'.$seatS.'" ');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["Eventid"]);
 $stmt->execute();
else
{
 $now = time();
**check current time and if session time is over update second query**
         if ($now > $_SESSION['expire']) {
            session_destroy();
            $seat=$_POST['finalSeats'];
            $Eventid=$_POST["Eventid"];
**sql Injection Protect**
```

$stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE fistevent SET `Status`=" " where `Event_Id`=? AND `seats`="'.$seat.'" AND `Status`="Hold" ');
                 $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["Eventid"]);
                 $stmt->execute();

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Learn to use prepared statements

Comment: i'll use mysqli_real_escape_string() for that. currently iam working on localhost. so do you have an idea to solve that?

Comment: You can't execute anything after browser is closed. Usually people solve it by storing "last active" timestamps.

Comment: As for SQL, please watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY. That should explain the issue with injections (and, btw, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` only make it harder to create an injection, but does not prevent it).

Comment: ok.i'll watch it. but can you tell me how to update table on session timeout or user back the browser.

Comment: You can make a ajax request on the onunload event off the browser. but a onunload event is also triggerd when reloading a webpage..

Comment: @krishna there is no way for php to know, that user clicked "back button". You could hack it together with JS somehow, but it would not be reliable. And there is no way for PHP to trigger an action, when session times out. Re-design your application. Your current approach is not compatible with the nature of internet.

Comment: Sir can u please look the code and tell me is it ok for SQL INJECTION ATTACK? I just update the code the Query u mention last time